# Sublime Text 2 - OS X Command Line

Tags: bash, terminal, sublimetext2

Original Sublime 2 [instruction](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) for enabling editor to launch from command line:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

do not work in Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create the `~/bin` directory if it doesn't already exist:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

Then run the `ln` again. Make sure that directory is added to your `$PATH` by adding this to the ~/.bashrc file, creating it if it doesn't exist:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
```

If you don't use bash, use your manual to figure out how to add a directory to your `$PATH` variable.

This is actually what the instructions say:

> The first task is to make a symlink to subl. Assuming you've placed
>   Sublime Text 2 in the Applications folder, **and that you have a ~/bin
>   directory in your path**, you can run: [snip]

This implies you need to create the `~/bin` directory if it doesn't exist, and add it to your `$PATH` if it is not there already. The above instructions do exactly that.

If you don't like that ugly `bin` folder in your pretty home folder, you can use `chflags` to make it disappear from the Finder:

```
chflags hidden ~/bin
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, but every time I close and reopen my terminal, I am forced to re-input export PATH="$PATH:~/bin", any idea how to make this stick? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It seems you missed step 2 about the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: my bin folder is within Users/myname/bin. It contains subl. How can I make it so that this is used?

Comment: ~ means "your home folder", so ~/.bashrc means "the file called .bashrc inside /Users/myname". Create that file, and put the `export PATH="$PATH:~/bin"` line in it. The changes will apply to every subsequent terminal window.

Answer (score 11):

Change target directory to system folder /usr/bin and use sudo for admin rights.

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl
```

Comment: This works only because in OSX /bin is already on $PATH and ~/bin by default is not.

Comment: Don't add stuff to `/bin`. `/bin` should be reserved for built-in executables. `/usr/bin` is the right place for non-system executables available for all users (and `~/bin` is the right place for non-system executables available for just you).

Comment: OK, thanks! I found an solution that works, but was not right conceptually. Good to know.

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into this problem on OSX Mountain Lion and then again on Mavericks. This solution worked for me:

Create the bin directory in /usr/local/bin if it doesn't already exist:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
```

You have to use sudo and enter your password to create the directory because it is inside a system folder.

Setup `subl` as a command-line command in the /usr/local/bin:

```bsh
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

The directory /usr/local/bin is already in your `$PATH` by default, even if it doesn't exist yet, so there is no need to add it to your `$PATH`. The folder /usr/local is also the folder used for git and homebrew installs, so it makes sense to keep all your local command-line commands in this location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its already here, but this one worked like a charm for me:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```